# ARDUINO MKR CONNECTOR CARRIERは3.3Vでは動作しないのでしょうか？

Tags: arduino

[ARDUINO MKR WAN 1310](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/mkr-wan-1310)と[ARDUINO MKR CONNECTOR CARRIER](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-mkr-connector-carrier)に[SCD30](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-CO2_Temperature_Humidity_Sensor-SCD30/)を接続しています。
MKR WAN 1310にUSBにて給電した場合、SCD30から値を読み取りLoRaWANにてTTNへ送信することができます。
しかし、3.7Vのリチウムイオン電池から給電すると、SCD30が動作していないようです。

ひょっとしてMKR CONNECTOR CARRIERは5Vしか対応していないのでしょうか。

稚拙な質問で恐縮ですが、知識のある方がいましたらご教授ください。

Answer (score 0):

[ARDUINO MKR WAN 1310](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/mkr-wan-1310)　のページに、「Board Power Supply (USB/VIN)   5V」と書かれています。
『MKR CONNECTOR CARRIERは5Vしか対応していない』ということでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

参照先ページの「TECH SPECS」と「FAQ」のタブに書いてありますよ。
ついでにMKR CONNECTOR CARRIERの方は 7V - 16V が必要なようです。
**追記:** 他に「TECH SPECS」「DOCUMENTATION」にバッテリの記述がありますが、それでも3.7Vのようです。

ARDUINO MKR WAN 1310

> - 「TECH SPECS」
>
>   - Board Power Supply (USB/VIN)    5V
>   - Supported Batteries  rechargeable Li-Ion, or Li-Po, 1024 mAh minimum capacity
> - 「DOCUMENTATION」
>   Pinout Diagram に Li-Po 3.7 V (バッテリ)
> - 「FAQ」
>   Batteries, Pins and board LEDs
>   Vin: This pin can be used to power the board with a regulated 5V source. If the power is fed through this pin, the USB power source is disconnected. This is the only way you can supply 5v (range is 5V to maximum 6V) to the board not using USB. This pin is an INPUT.
>   Vin：このピンは、安定化された5Vソースでボードに電力を供給するために使用できます。 このピンから電力が供給されている場合、USB電源は切断されています。 これは、USBを使用しないボードに5v（範囲は5Vから最大6V）を供給する唯一の方法です。 このピンは入力です。

---

ARDUINO MKR CONNECTOR CARRIER (GROVE COMPATIBLE)

> - 「TECH SPECS」
>   input Voltage (screw terminal block)    7V - 16V ([Buck Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54232.pdf))

---

こちらは使用する方の電圧でしょうね。

Grove - CO2 & Temperature & Humidity Sensor (SCD30)

> - Specification
>   Supply voltage  3.3V / 5V

Comment: MKR WAN 1310が動作するためには5Vが必要なのですね。
DocumentationにあるPinout Diagramの図ではバッテリーの電圧は3.7Vとなっています。
これが誤りで、5Vのバッテリーが必要なのでしょうか。
もし、図が正して3.7Vの場合、このバッテリーがなんのためにあるのか分かりません。。。

Comment: すみません、頂いた回答を理解できていませんでした。
3.7Vのバッテリーは「MKR WAN 1310」を動作させるもので、「MKR CONNECTOR CARRIER」を動作させるためには別途7V～16Vのバッテリーをねじ端子に繋ぐ必要がある、ということですね。

Comment: そうだと思います。`Li-Po 3.7V`と書いてあるので、「TECH SPECS」の`Supported Batteries rechargeable Li-Ion, or Li-Po, 1024 mAh minimum capacity`の部分ですかね。「OVERVIEW」の`Improved Battery Power`の部分の説明に関係するのでしょうが、おそらくUSB/5V以外でも本体だけ？ならリチウムバッテリで動作するのでしょう。

Comment: 「ARDUINO MKR CONNECTOR CARRIER」に9Vの角形電池を接続することで解決しました。乾電池の＋はVINではなく5Vに繋ぐのが正しいみたいです。また、この場合は「ARDUINO MKR WAN 1310」のリチウムイオン電池は不要でした。

Comment: まあおそらくMKR CONNECTOR CARRIERに電源が接続されていれば、他へはそこから供給されるのでしょうね。